# How to make a tabular list of formulas with fixed width?

Tags: tables, column-width

I want to type a well known list of famous formulas.

[image: What I want to type]

So far I did

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\begin{tabular}{llll}
1. & Teorema de Pitágoras          & $a^2+b^2=c^2$           & Pitágoras, 530 a.C. \\ 
2. & Logaritmos                    & $\log xy=\log x+\log y$ & Juan Napier, 1610   \\ 
3. & Cálculo                       & $1+1=2$                 & Newton, 1668        \\ 
4. & Ley de Gravedad               & $G=g$                   & Newton, 1687        \\ 
5. & La raíz cuadrada de menos uno & $i^2=-1$                & Euler, 1750         \\ 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image: What I did]

As you can see I couldn't make to fix the width of the fifth row of the second column.

Comment: What do you mean by __fix the width of the fifth row of the second column__? Please elaborate. Do you mean all three columns should have the same width?

Comment: La raíz cuadrada de menos uno should look like The Square Root of Minus One (using two rows instead of one, as the first image).

Comment: You can use a p type column with a width of your choice.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest you set the overall width of the table to `\textwidth`, use a `tabularx` environment, and employ an `X` column for the second column to allow automatic line-breaking, as needed. (The `X` column *is* a `p` column, whose width is calculated for you by LaTeX.) In addition, I would like to suggest typesetting the contents of the third columns in display-style math mode automatically.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel} % optional
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
% define a modified version of the 'X' column type:
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\bfseries}X} 
% automatic display-math mode, left-aligned:
\newcolumntype{N}{>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}} 

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.333}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l L N l @{}}
\toprule
1. & Teorema de Pitágoras          & a^2+b^2=c^2           & Pitágoras, 530 a.C. \\ 
2. & Logaritmos                    & \log xy=\log x+\log y & Juan Napier, 1610   \\ 
3. & Cálculo                       & 1+1=2                 & Newton, 1668        \\ 
4. & Ley de Gravedad               & G=g                   & Newton, 1687        \\ 
5. & La raíz cuadrada de menos uno & i^2=-1                & Euler, 1750         \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

---

*Addendum*: A nice way to extend this setup is to enable automatic line numbering. The following example shows how this might be achieved.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}

% define a modified version of the 'X' column type:
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash\bfseries}X}
% further modifications to 'X' column type, such as hanging indentation:
\newcounter{tabcounter}
\newlength{\mylen}  \settowidth{\mylen}{1.\kern6pt} % compute amount of hanging indentation
\newcolumntype{M}{>{\hangafter=1\hangindent\mylen%
                    \stepcounter{tabcounter}%
                    \textmd{\thetabcounter.\kern6pt}}L}
\newcolumntype{N}{>{$\displaystyle}l<{$}} % automatic display-math mode

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.333}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} M N l @{}}
\toprule
Teorema de Pitágoras          & a^2+b^2=c^2           & Pitágoras, 530 a.C. \\ 
Logaritmos                    & \log xy=\log x+\log y & Juan Napier, 1610   \\ 
Cálculo                       & 1+1=2                 & Newton, 1668        \\ 
Ley de Gravedad               & G=g                   & Newton, 1687        \\ 
La raíz cuadrada de menos uno & i=\sqrt{-1}           & Euler, 1750         \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Possibly easiest method, break the long rows manually as you wish. Other options include using `p` type column with a specified width, a `tabularx` that's `\linewidth` wide with `{lX{$}X<{$}X}` columns, etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{ll>{$}l<{$} l}
1. & Teorema de Pitágoras          & a^2+b^2=c^2           & Pitágoras, 530 a.C. \\ 
2. & Logaritmos                    & \log xy=\log x+\log y & Juan Napier, 1610   \\ 
3. & Cálculo                       & 1+1=2                 & Newton, 1668        \\ 
4. & Ley de Gravedad               & G=g                   & Newton, 1687        \\ 
5. & La raíz cuadrada de           & i^2=-1                & Euler, 1750         \\ 
   & menos uno                     &                       &                     \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. You may want to insert a `\centering` instruction before `\begin{tabular}`.

Comment: Srue, I added that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using leandriis advice and adding \setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt} to separate a little bit more the columns, I did this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}[2cm]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{12pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{lp{3.4cm}lll}
1. & Teorema de Pitágoras          & $a^2+b^2=c^2$           & Pitágoras, 530 a.C. \\ 
2. & Logaritmos                    & $\log xy=\log x+\log y$ & Juan Napier, 1610   \\ 
3. & Cálculo                       & $1+1=2$                 & Newton, 1668        \\ 
4. & Ley de Gravedad               & $G=g$                   & Newton, 1687        \\ 
5. & La raíz cuadrada de menos uno & $i^2=-1$                & Euler, 1750          
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is what I was looking for.

Comment: You're right. Your solution was excellent. Thanks!